# Noun that refers to "amount of (psychological) stress a given thing causes"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Is there a *noun* that refers to "the amount of stress that a given thing causes" (i.e. "how stressful is this thing"), or, as a less ideal alternative, "the intensity of the emotional response that a given thing induces"?

The context is, I have a column in an organizational spreadsheet that is basically "how much is this *bothering* me?", in a very vague sense. I'm using this as the main criteria for prioritizing tasks. I need a good single-word heading for the column.

"Stressiness" is my current made-up word of choice, but I'd prefer a real word, or at least something with a more professional tone. AmE preferred but BrE / AuE also work.

To be clear, afaik I'm not looking for a synonym for "stress". I'm looking for a word that means "the amount of stress *caused / induced* by something". I *think* there's a difference between the two, but maybe I'm just splitting hairs? Or perhaps there *is* a difference but English does not have the words to represent it.

Comment: Isn't this a matter of opinion from a synonym list? I'd go with **worry**.

Comment: @WeatherI don't know the answer to your question since I don't know what words are available. Synonyms to what, though? To be clear I'm not looking for a synonym to "stress". I'm looking for a word that means "the amount of stress *caused / induced by* something". Or i.e. "how stressful is a given thing". So "worry" isn't quite what I'm looking for, "worry" is the feeling, "the amount of worry caused by something" is the concept I'm trying to put into a word. I *think* there's a difference, or am I splitting hairs?

Comment: I did indeed consult a list for 'stress' and thought that 'worry' might be a nice short heading that could carry a score or rating, because "How much of a worry is it?" aligns with "How much is this bothering me?"

Comment: I am now wondering if maybe there *is* a difference between "the feeling of stress / worry" and "amount of stress / worry induced", but it's really subtle and not capturable with English. Like one of those ideas where Japanese (or something; I don't know Japanese) has 1000 words for it and English only has one.

Comment: A **worry** can be the thing itself, or what it causes.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the former sense, wouldn't it be more of a synonym for "stressor"? If so, then is there a distinction between "stress", "stressor", and "the amount of stress caused by a stressor"?

Comment: E.g. to use my made-up word "A stressor / worry with high *stressiness* causes a great amount of stress / worry." Or am I just being difficult (completely possible)?

Comment: OK then, looking up 'worry' I find [**vexation**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vexation).

Comment: Thanks for your help; really do appreciate it. I'm going to throw myself down a dictionary rabbit hole with "worry" and "vexation" and see if something appropriate pops out. I completely support closing this question if it is indeed merely a synonym request.

Comment: The Yiddish word _tsuris_ has this meaning.

Comment: It's not an existing use, but if I had to coin a use I would call such a concept a stressor's "stress load." But for practical purposes, I would simply use "stress" as you have in several examples. "How much stress does this cause you?" "How stressful is this?" ("Extremely stressful / somewhat stressful / mildly stressful..." etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is such a word. Seems to me that any level of stress, low or high or in between, needs an apposite adjective.

Nevertheless, here are a few suggestions:

- cognitive dissonance, or just *dissonance*
- angst
- agitation
- disquietude

In the last one, disquietude, *quietude* turns into its opposite with the *dis-* prefix. That means quietude turns into something it is not. One goes from quietude to something that is not quietude. The 180-degree change from one to the other is, by implication, an amount or level of change.

Every apposite noun I can think of carries with it an implied opposite. Only by modifying the noun or its negative with an adjective can you indicate the level or degree of the mental state (e.g., anxiety, worry, anxiousness, trepidation, boldness, compassion, hatred, and so on).

Another two-word solution might use the word *factor*, as in "the anxiety factor." Even then, however, you'd likely need more information to meet your criterion of *level* or *degree,* as in "level of anxiety factor."

Difficult question to answer.